# How to select only the rows that have a certain value in one column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, bind

I am doing an exploratory analysis of a dataset that includes the amount of games and how much they sold per platform in the last 20 years.

I want to select all the games that were released on a Nintendo platform, what I've done to achieve this is:

```
dfNintendo <- dfNintendo[dfNintendo$Platform=="GBA", ]
```

It works to extract only the games that were published on the Nintendo GBA, but I don't know how to extract multiple rows with tags different than GBA at the same time, I've tried with:

```
dfNintendo <- dfNintendo[dfNintendo$Platform=="GBA" | 
                         dfNintendo$Platform=="Wii" | 
                         dfNintendo$Platform=="WiiU", ]
```

But it doesn't work, I end up with an empty data.frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

**Base R**

```
dfNintendo[dfNintendo$Platform %in% c("GBA", "Wii", "WiiU"), ]
```

or

```
subset(dfNintendo, Platform %in% c("GBA", "Wii", "WiiU"))
```

**dplyr package**

```
dplyr::filter(dfNintendo, Platform %in% c("GBA", "Wii", "WiiU"))
```

These should do what you want

Comment: I tried those three options, the first one created a dataframe with a single NA row.
The second and third options made an empty dataframe

Comment: My bad, I had to reload the entire dataset and create the complete data.frame in order to make this work. Thanks a lot for your help.